# Finding derivative of $F(x)=\int_{x^3}^{x^6}(2t-1)^3dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives

> Find the derivative of the following function using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:
>   $$F(x)=\int_{x^3}^{x^6}(2t-1)^3dt$$

I don't know how to do this problem using FTOC because this is not a bounded function...

The answer that I got (which is wrong) was: $$6(2x^3-1)^2(3x^2)+6(2x^6-1)^4(12x^5)$$

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t) dt= f(b(x))b'(x)-f(a(x))a'(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ah, You're not at all supposed to differentiate terms inside the integral

See, Using FTC

$$F(x)=\int_{x^3}^{x^6}(2t-1)^3dt=\int_{0}^{x^6}(2t-1)^3dt-\int_0^{x^3}(2t-1)^3dt$$

$$\begin{align}
F'(x)&=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\int_{0}^{x^6}(2t-1)^3dt-\int_0^{x^3}(2t-1)^3dt\right]\\
&=(2x^6-1)^3\cdot6x^5-(2x^3-1)^3\cdot3x^2\\
&=6x^5(2x^6-1)^3-3x^2(2x^3-1)^3\\
\end{align}$$

Using Leibniz rule

$$F(x)=\int_{x^3}^{x^6}(2t-1)^3dt$$

$$\begin{align}
F'(x)
&=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x^3}^{x^6}(2t-1)^3dt\\
&=(2x^6-1)^3\cdot6x^5-(2x^3-1)^3\cdot 3x^2
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

By fundamental theorem of calculus and chain rule
$$F(x)=\int_{x^3}^{x^6}(2t-1)^3dt\\
F'(x)=\left[\int_{x^3}^{x^6}g(t)dt\right]',g(t)=(2t-1)^3\\
=\left[G(x^6)-G(x^3)\right]'
=(x^6)'g(x^6)-(x^3)'g(x^3)\\
=6x^5(2x^6-1)^3-3x^2(2x^3-1)^3
$$